# listView.setAdapter is so sluggish?

Tags: android, listview

I have three swipable tabs. In the first tab, I have a listview with more than 1000 items.

I tried to fill the list using Asynctask and Runnable and I have no problem with that.

The problem is when I am trying to assign the adapter to the listview. I noticed no matter how many items are in the adapter, whether it is 1 or 1000, when it tries to do: listView.setAdapter(adapter), it skips around 30 frames...

Since listView.setAdapter(adapter) is used in the first tab, whenever the user tries to enter that tab, UI freezes for some milliseconds. Although it is not a serious problem, but I don't like it.

The question is: Is this normal that when we invoke listView.setAdapter(adapter) the UI freezes for some milliseconds and skips some frames? Is there not anyway to fix this?

Am I Clear?

```
    Carpet_handler ch; // my db handler
ListView listview;

public ArrayList<CarpetGen> carpetGens;
CarpetAdapter adapter;
boolean loadingMore=false;
int offset;
Context ctx;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first_page_customers, container, false);
    ch=new Carpet_handler(getActivity()); // db handler
    listview = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView2);
    ctx=this.getActivity();
    carpetGens = new ArrayList<CarpetGen>();
    offset=0;
    adapter = new CarpetAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.row, carpetGens);



    listview.setAdapter(adapter); // adapter is empty first time, runnable fills it
    listview.setOnItemClickListener(myClickListener);



    //Here is where the magic happens
    listview.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener(){
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {}
        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
            int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            //what is the bottom iten that is visible
            int lastInScreen = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;
            //is the bottom item visible & not loading more already ? Load more !
            if((lastInScreen == totalItemCount) && !(loadingMore)){
                Thread thread =  new Thread(null, loadMoreListItems);
                thread.start();
            }
        }
    });


    return rootView;
}



   //Runnable to load the items
   private Runnable loadMoreListItems = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Set flag so we cant load new items 2 at the same time
        loadingMore = true;
        //Reset the array that holds the new items
        carpetGens= new ArrayList<CarpetGen>();
        carpetGens.addAll(ch.getAllCustomerCarpets1(getActivity().getIntent().getIntExtra("recordid", -1), offset));
        offset+=15;
        //Done! now continue on the UI thread
        if(getActivity()==ctx)
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(returnRes);

    }
};

//Since we cant update our UI from a thread this Runnable takes care of that!
private Runnable returnRes = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Loop thru the new items and add them to the adapter
        if(carpetGens != null && carpetGens.size() > 0){
                    for(int i=0;i < carpetGens.size();i++)
                    adapter.add(carpetGens.get(i));
                 }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                loadingMore = false;
        }
   };
```

Here is my adapter:

```
public class CarpetAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CarpetGen> {

private final Context context;
private final int rowResourceId;
//private final String[] Ids;
private final ArrayList<CarpetGen> Objects;

public CarpetAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<CarpetGen> objects){//Arr[] objects) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.context = context;
    this.rowResourceId = textViewResourceId;
    this.Objects = objects;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    View rowView = convertView;
    CarpetGen i = Objects.get(position);
    if (rowView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
        //TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView);

        //textView.setText(i.Result_String);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.title = (TextView) rowView
                .findViewById(R.id.textView);

        rowView.setTag(holder);            
    } else {        
        holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
    }

    holder.title.setText(i.Result_String);



    return rowView;

}
static class ViewHolder {
TextView title;
```

}
}

Comment: Updated the first post, included my custom arrayadapter.

Comment: I found the solution. It was because of the custom textviews that i used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's perfectly normal. Keep in mind that it has to refresh the layout, even if it has zero elements, when you call the `setAdapter()` method, you're doing some operations which depends on your implementation, but basically it's not a 0-second-miracle. As @laalto suggested, there also might be a bottleneck in the custom adapter implementation, so you might want to consider doing some work in `Thread`s (or basically the `AsyncThread`). But as I said, I'd not worry about it (overall, if this frame skipping was happening in a virtual device).

Comment: I wish it is normal. the test was on a real device (not emulator). And as i mentioned i tried Asynstask before, it is still the same.

Comment: If you've tried to move to `Thread`s (or `AsyncTask`s in your case) your hardest work and still remains, I'd really not worry about it. As I said, it depends on several factors, and one is your implementation. If you've tried to optimize it and it still remains, it's due to the layout processing, so there's nothing else to do.

Comment: I have also suspected it is due to layout processing. just wanted to hear this from somebody else to be sure :D

Answer (score 0):

i think you should try to do the following  :

1st - use AsyncTask to load the items in the doInBakground method .

2nd - listView.setAdapter in the AsyncTask in the doPostExecute method .

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you, but since the PostExecute runs on UI thread, the problem still remains. I tried this solution, it still skips some frames.

Comment: you can try to make a thread in your customAdapter that loads the data and then run it in your UI thread , maybe this will give you some time .